# Add or replace email provider suffix in an email input

Tags: html, jquery, css, button, text

After you'd click on one of the buttons, it should fill or replace the text, so its a valid E-Mail Adress. 
For example, if you have `test123` and click on the gmail-button, it should insert `@gmail.com` after it.
But if you have `test123@outlook.com`, it should remove the "@outlook.com" and replace it with the text on the button. (clicking on gmail-button = `test123@gmail.com` and so on...)

Short form:
If you click onto the button, remove all after the "@" and replace it with the text that is in the button.

Update:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" value="" id="text" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Adress" style="width: 300px;" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="@gmail.com" id="gmail-button"/>
<input type="button" value="@outlook.com" id="outlook-button"/>
```

**JS + jQuery (3.4.1):**

```
function cleanText(value){
    return value.replace(/(@.+)$/, '')
}

$(function () {
    $('#gmail-button').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#text');
        text.val(cleanText(text.val()) + '@gmail.com');    
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#outlook-button').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#text');
        text.val(cleanText(text.val()) + '@outlook.com');    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expressions you can easily remove the suffixes. Try this:

```js
function cleanText(value){
    return value.replace(/(@.+.com)$/, '')
}

$(function () {
    $('#gmail-button').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#text');
        text.val(cleanText(text.val()) + '@gmail.com');    
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#outlook-button').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#text');
        text.val(cleanText(text.val()) + '@outlook.com');    
    });
});
```

Comment: in the 2nd line I have replaced ``(/(@.+.com)$/, '')`` with just ``(/(@.+)$/, '')`` so it replaces all after the "@" and not just if its with "@" and ends with ".com".

Comment: That works better. Good.